# Display keys in yaml-files that contain property

Tags: yaml, yq

Given the following yaml file:

```yaml
service1:
  host:  s1
  port:  27000
service2:
  host:  s2
  port:  27001
service3:
  host:  s3
service4:
  host:  s4
  port:  27004
```

I want to list all keys, whose objects contain a "port" field.

Expected output:

```
- service1
- service2
- service4
```

Using the following command returns all keys, including "service3":

```bash
./yq 'keys | .[] comments=""' file.yml
```

However, since service3 does not have a port, it should be omitted.
I tried using [filter](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/filter), [has](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/has), [map](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/map), [select](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/select), ..., but couldn't achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using the following command:
>
> ```
> ./yq 'keys | .[] comments=""' file.yml
> ```
>
> ...returns all keys, including "service3".

This does not test for any existence of "port".

You could `map` the items to their `key`, and `select` only those having an own key given using `has`:

```bash
yq 'map(select(has("port")) | key)' file.yml
```

```yaml
- service1
- service2
- service4
```

Tested with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version v4.34.2